# UILabel not hidden when set to Hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app receives a measurement every minute. When the measurement is 0, I want a label to be displayed in the middle. When it is greater than that, when I want the label to disappear. The issue I have is that once the label appears, it doesn't hide once I set its hidden mode to true.

```
 UILabel *emptyBagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    emptyBagLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    emptyBagLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    emptyBagLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    emptyBagLabel.text = @"EMPTY POUCH";
    emptyBagLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    emptyBagLabel.hidden = true;

    [self addSubview:emptyBagLabel];

    [emptyBagLabel.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [emptyBagLabel.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
    [emptyBagLabel.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.widthAnchor].active = YES;
    [emptyBagLabel.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active= YES;

    if (measurement == 0 || measurement <= 0.005) {
        emptyBagLabel.hidden = false;
    }

    if (measurement > 0.005) {
        emptyBagLabel.hidden = true;
    }
```

I've been scratching my head at this for a while, a bit frustrated with how I'm not able to solve such a trivial issue. The method I have it in is called every minute. I know the method and the hidden = true line are getting called, so I'm unsure as to what is causing the issue.

Comment: But you're creating a new label every time that method is called, not hiding the previous one

Comment: i see, then how should I go about handling this?

Comment: You hold a reference to your first label, then call `.hidden = true` on that label

Comment: That still seems to not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subview that are added programmatically ought to be added lazily, so you get exactly one subview instance.  I'd refactor the code like this...

```
- (UILabel *)emptyBagLabel {
    UILabel *emptyBagLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:128];
    if (!emptyBagLabel) {
        emptyBagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        emptyBagLabel.tag = 128;

        // set all of the attributes her for how the label looks, textColor, etc.
        // everything except the properties that change over time

        [self addSubview:emptyBagLabel];
    }
    return emptyBagLabel;
}

// if this view is built using initWithFrame...
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self emptyBagLabel];  // to add the label initially
    }
    return self;
}

// if this view is ever loaded from a nib, then
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self emptyBagLabel];
    }
    return self;

}

// elsewhere in the view, when you get the measurement
// side note: alpha is usually a better choice than hidden because you can animate it
if (measurement == 0 || measurement <= 0.005) {
    self.emptyBagLabel.alpha = 1.0;
}

if (measurement > 0.005) {
    self.emptyBagLabel.alpha = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: I dont have access to self.emptyBagLabel

Comment: @FaisalSyed that's the method supplied in the answer.  If you add that method, `self.emptyBagLabel` or more properly `[self emptyBagLabel]` will work just fine.

Comment: Ah I see. Also this code is in -(void)drawRect for a UIView so I don't have access to viewDidLayoutSubviews. Should I just add the label in the init method?

Comment: Init method is a little early.  Definitely not in drawRect, because we're just manipulating view hierarchy.  didAppear or didLayoutSubviews are the common and correct choices to make the initial call to self.emptyBagelLabel

Comment: Dumb question, but will didLayoutSubviews be called for a UIView and not ViewController?

Comment: Not a dumb question!  I didn't realize you were in a view (thought it was view controller).  You can make the first call in initWithFrame, or initWithCoder (if this view comes from a nib)

Comment: Awesome, let me try that and will get back to you

Comment: So the label properly is displayed for empty measurements, however when a greater value is received the label still doesn't go back to hidden. Perhaps I should call it on the main queue?

Comment: The label remains hidden until it's shown, and then it never goes back to hidden no matter how I try to hide it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134428/discussion-between-danh-and-faisal-syed).